# Table has multiple records in which mobileNumber column is in only few records . I need to get those records only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Table has multiple records in which mobileNumber column is in only few records . I need to get those records only.

By this query i am getting all records.

```
$request = [
    'TableName' => 'tbl_camp',
    'ExpressionAttributeNames' => [
        '#mobileNumber' => 'mobileNumber'
    ],
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
        ':val1' => ['S' => 'NULL']
    ],
    'FilterExpression' => '#mobileNumber <> :val1',
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `attribute_exists()` function to filter out items with whether certain attribute present.

Your query becomes something like this:

```
$request = [
    'TableName' => 'tbl_camp',
    'ExpressionAttributeNames' => [
        '#mobileNumber' => 'mobileNumber'
    ],
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
        ':val1' => ['S' => 'NULL']
    ],
    'FilterExpression' => 'attribute_exists(#mobileNumber)',
];
```

You can read about this at [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html).

Comment: Thanks @Parth Modi